# Как сделать, чтобы при вводе фамилии слово начиналось с большой буквы

Tags: css

При вводе текста в поля с ФИО, каждое слово должно начинаться  с
большой буквы, даже если пользователь будет вводить ФИО с маленькой
буквы. То же самое касается и полей на странице с контактами.

Как это сделать, следующий код не помог

```
input[type="surname"]:first-letter {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; /* Гарнитура шрифта первой буквы */
    font-size: 2em; /* Размер шрифта первого символа */
    color: red; /* Красный цвет текста */
}
```

Comment: А если кто-то иероглифами введёт из китайцев?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics, у китайцев есть [пиньинь](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwie7IHiu-_WAhUkQZoKHV28ChcQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%259F%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D1%258C%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D1%258C&usg=AOvVaw3xFE565NmLxTZ6Vcif39xV).

Answer (score 5):

```css
input{
  text-transform: capitalize;  
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <label for="name">Имя</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```